# Problem with cast convert and view all in TSQL

Tags: sql, casting

I have a view called vw_FormatTable1 which contains

```
Convert( CHAR ( <SIZE> ), Coalesce (Convert (VarChar, [<FIELD>],120),'')) AS [<FIELD>]
```

where `<SIZE>` is the width of the field to be output and `<FIELD>` is the field name

And this basic block is repeated for all approx 600 fields in my base table creating a view of over 50,000 characters.

My problem is as follows:

```
select 
  [CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_1],
  CONVERT(CHAR(3), COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_1]), '')) AS [CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_SPC]
from Table1
group by [CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_1]
```

produces different results from

```
select 
   [CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_1],
   CONVERT(CHAR(3), COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_1]),'')) AS [CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_SPC]
from vw_FormatTable1
group by [CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_1]
```

and I do not know why?

The first output is

```
[CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_1]     [CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_SPC]
--------------------------    --------------------------
001                           001
002                           002
```

whereas the second output is

```
[CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_1]     [CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_SPC]
--------------------------    --------------------------
1                             1
2                             2
```

The inclusion of the 120 is not causing this error (as I done some basic testing with and without it and it does not make a difference)

Can anyone answer:

- Why I am losing the leading zeros
- Why Cannot a not replicate the result in my first SQL statement?
- Is there a size limit on views?

Thanks in advance,

HighFever

---

A snippet of the view is:

`ALTER View [dbo].[vw_ver2_InpatientsLong_ReadyToExport]
AS
select top 100 percent 
Convert(CHAR(6),coalesce(convert(varchar,[PRIME RECIPIENT],120),'')) AS [PRIME RECIPIENT],
Convert(CHAR(6),coalesce(convert(varchar,[COPY RECIPIENT 1],120),'')) AS [COPY RECIPIENT 1],
Convert(CHAR(6),coalesce(convert(varchar,[COPY RECIPIENT 2],120),'')) AS [COPY RECIPIENT 2],
Convert(CHAR(6),coalesce(convert(varchar,[COPY RECIPIENT 3],120),'')) AS [COPY RECIPIENT 3],
Convert(CHAR(6),coalesce(convert(varchar,[COPY RECIPIENT 4],120),'')) AS [COPY RECIPIENT 4],
Convert(CHAR(6),coalesce(convert(varchar,[COPY RECIPIENT 5],120),'')) AS [COPY RECIPIENT 5],
Convert(CHAR(5),coalesce(convert(varchar,[SENDER],120),'')) AS [SENDER],
Convert(CHAR(3),coalesce(convert(varchar,[CDS_GROUP],120),'')) AS [CDS GROUP],
Convert(CHAR(3),coalesce(convert(varchar,[CDS_TYPE],120),'')) AS [CDS TYPE],
Convert(CHAR(35),coalesce(convert(varchar,[CDS_ID],120),'')) AS [CDS_ID],
Convert(CHAR(1),coalesce(convert(varchar,[TEST_FLAG],120),'')) AS [TEST_FLAG],
Convert(CHAR(1),coalesce(convert(varchar,[UPDATE TYPE],120),'')) AS [UPDATE TYPE],
Convert(CHAR(3),coalesce(convert(varchar,[PROTOCOL IDENTIFIER],120),'')) AS [PROTOCOL IDENTIFIER],
Convert(CHAR(10),coalesce(convert(varchar,[BULKSTART],120),'')) AS [BULKSTART],
Convert(CHAR(10),coalesce(convert(varchar,[BULKEND],120),'')) AS [BULKEND],
Convert(CHAR(16),coalesce(convert(varchar,[DATETIME_CREATED],120),'')) AS [DATETIME_CREATED],
Convert(CHAR(5),coalesce(convert(varchar,[PROVIDER],120),'')) AS [PROVIDER],
Convert(CHAR(5),coalesce(convert(varchar,[PURCHASER],120),'')) AS [PURCHASER],
Convert(CHAR(6),coalesce(convert(varchar,[SERIAL_NO],120),'')) AS [SERIAL_NO],
Convert(CHAR(10),coalesce(convert(varchar,[CONTRACT_LINE_NO],120),'')) AS [CONTRACT_LINE_NO],
Convert(CHAR(17),coalesce(convert(varchar,[PURCH_REF],120),'')) AS [PURCH_REF],
Convert(CHAR(17),coalesce(convert(varchar,[NHS_NO],120),'')) AS [NHS_NO],
Convert(CHAR(2),coalesce(convert(varchar,[NNN_STATUS_IND],120),'')) AS [NNN_STATUS_IND],
Convert(CHAR(1),coalesce(convert(varchar,[name_format],120),'')) AS [name_status],
Convert(CHAR(1),coalesce(convert(varchar,[address_format],120),'')) AS [address_status],
Convert(CHAR(70),coalesce(convert(varchar,[NAME],120),'')) AS [NAME],
Convert(CHAR(35),coalesce(convert(varchar,[FORENAME],120),'')) AS [FORENAME],
Convert(CHAR(35),coalesce(convert(varchar,[HOMEADD1],120),'')) AS [HOMEADD1],
Convert(CHAR(35),coalesce(convert(varchar,[HOMEADD2],120),'')) AS [HOMEADD2],
Convert(CHAR(35),coalesce(convert(varchar,[HOMEADD3],120),'')) AS [HOMEADD3],
Convert(CHAR(35),coalesce(convert(varchar,[HOMEADD4],120),'')) AS [HOMEADD4],
Convert(CHAR(35),coalesce(convert(varchar,[HOMEADD5],120),'')) AS [HOMEADD5],
Convert(CHAR(8),coalesce(convert(varchar,[POSTCODE],120),'')) AS [POSTCODE],
Convert(CHAR(3),coalesce(convert(varchar,[HA],120),'')) AS [HA],
Convert(CHAR(1),coalesce(convert(varchar,[SEX],120),'')) AS [SEX],
Convert(CHAR(2),coalesce(convert(varchar,[CARER_SUPPORT_IND],120),'')) AS [CARER_SUPPORT_IND],
Convert(CHAR(10),coalesce(convert(varchar,[DOB],120),'')) AS [DOB],
Convert(CHAR(8),coalesce(convert(varchar,[GPREG],120),'')) AS [GPREG],
Convert(CHAR(6),coalesce(convert(varchar,[PRACREG],120),'')) AS [PRACREG],
Convert(CHAR(2),coalesce(convert(varchar,[ETHNICOR],120),'')) AS [ETHNICOR],
Convert(CHAR(10),coalesce(convert(varchar,[LOCPATID],120),'')) AS [LOCPATID],
Convert(CHAR(8),coalesce(convert(varchar,[REFERRER],120),'')) AS [REFERRER],
Convert(CHAR(6),coalesce(convert(varchar,[REF_ORG],120),'')) AS [REF_ORG],
Convert(CHAR(12),coalesce(convert(varchar,[PROV_SPELL],120),'')) AS [PROV_SPELL],
Convert(CHAR(2),coalesce(convert(varchar,[ADMIN_CATEGORY],120),'')) AS [ADMIN_CATEGORY],
Convert(CHAR(2),coalesce(convert(varchar,[LEGAL_STATUS],120),'')) AS [LEGAL_STATUS],`

*Many Lines*

Convert(CHAR(10),coalesce(convert(varchar,[MOM_NHS_NUM],120),'')) AS [MOM_NHS_NUM],
Convert(CHAR(10),coalesce(convert(varchar,[MOM_PAT_ID],120),'')) AS [MOM_PAT_ID],
Convert(CHAR(5),coalesce(convert(varchar,[MOM_PAT_ID_ORG],120),'')) AS [MOM_PAT_ID_ORG],
Convert(CHAR(2),coalesce(convert(varchar,[MOM_NNN_STATUS],120),'')) AS [MOM_NNN_STATUS],
Convert(CHAR(35),coalesce(convert(varchar,[MOM_USUAL_ADDRESSLINE_1],120),'')) AS [MOM_USUAL_ADDRESS_LINE_1],
Convert(CHAR(35),coalesce(convert(varchar,[MOM_USUAL_ADDRESSLINE_2],120),'')) AS [MOM_USUAL_ADDRESS_LINE_2],
Convert(CHAR(35),coalesce(convert(varchar,[MOM_USUAL_ADDRESSLINE_3],120),'')) AS [MOM_USUAL_ADDRESS_LINE_3],
Convert(CHAR(35),coalesce(convert(varchar,[MOM_USUAL_ADDRESSLINE_4],120),'')) AS [MOM_USUAL_ADDRESS_LINE_4],
Convert(CHAR(35),coalesce(convert(varchar,[MOM_USUAL_ADDRESSLINE_5],120),'')) AS [MOM_USUAL_ADDRESS_LINE_5],
Convert(CHAR(8),coalesce(convert(varchar,[MOM_POSTCODE_OF_USUAL_ADDRESS],120),'')) AS [MOM_POSTCODE_OF_USUAL_ADDRESS],
Convert(CHAR(17),coalesce(convert(varchar,[PROVIDER_REFERENCE_NUMBER],120),'')) AS [PROVIDER REFERENCE NUMBER],
Convert(CHAR(5),coalesce(convert(varchar,[ORGANISATION_CODE(LOCAL PAT ID)],120),'')) AS [ORGANISATION CODE (LOCAL PAT ID)],
Convert(CHAR(12),coalesce(convert(varchar,[UBRN],120),'')) AS [UBRN],
Convert(CHAR(20),coalesce(convert(varchar,[CARE_PATHWAY_ID],120),'')) AS [CARE_PATHWAY_ID],
Convert(CHAR(5),coalesce(convert(varchar,[CARE_PATWAY_ID_ORG],120),'')) AS [CARE_PATHWAY_ID_ORG],
Convert(CHAR(2),coalesce(convert(varchar,[REF_TO_TREAT_PERIOD_STATUS],120),'')) AS [REF_TO_TREAT_PERIOD_STATUS],
Convert(CHAR(10),coalesce(convert(varchar,[REF_TO_TREAT_PERIOD_START_DATE],120),'')) AS [REF_TO_TREAT_PERIOD_START_DATE],
Convert(CHAR(10),coalesce(convert(varchar,[REF_TO_TREAT_PERIOD_END_DATE],120),'')) AS [REF_TO_TREAT_PERIOD_END_DATE]
from tbl_SUS_CDS130

Comment: @user HTML tables aren't supported. Can you paste it in in plain text then select the code and use the code formatting button?

Comment: I have tried, is it any better?

Comment: You need to show us the definition of `vw_FormatTable1` for any useful analysis!

Comment: Any particular reason for that overly complicated, doubly-nested CONVERT?? Couldn't you just use `CONVERT(CHAR(3), COALESCE([CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_1], ''))` ... seems a bit pointless to convert to VARCHAR first and then to CHAR(3) right after that...

Comment: To save time, I wrote a genric convert statement, and replicated it (using excel) to come up with the full statement.  Do you think it will effect things?

Comment: Explain to me why you are doing this casting, it seems a pointless waste of seerver resources to me. Store the data the way you need to see it and convert it once not everytime you look at it. And then doing the conversiona again in the select? Why? What does the actual data in the orginating table look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing you do in the query with the formatting adds/removes leading zeros, so they must not be in the table.  Leading zeros can only exist in a string based data type column, and then only if they are put there on purpose.

My best guess based on all given information is that Table1.CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_1 is a char or varchar and has leading zeros in the column and that vw_FormatTable1.[CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_1] is an int (or a char/varchar with no leading zeros).

if you need leading zeros in the second query, use this:

```
select 
    [CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_1]
        ,RIGHT(ISNULL(REPLICATE('0',3)+CONVERT(VARCHAR, [CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_1]),''),3) AS [CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_SPC]
    from vw_FormatTable1 
    group by [CC_RENAL_SUPPORT_DAYS_1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had missed this field in the table def